# Cassandra secondary indices v. Lucene

Tags: cassandra, lucene

I understand that Cassandra is a NoSQL db and patching it with many indices is not the way to go, but here I'm looking at solution for my analytics cluster, not for the production/real-time one.

So I think it makes sense to add indices to reduce the amount of data filtered by Spark.

How do native Cassandra secondary indices compare to Lucene's indices?

Many functionalities are not available with Cassandra alone, but what about things that you can do with both?

Is it better / does it make sense to only use Lucene?

Another advantage that I see is that I can install Lucene only on my analytics cluster, without overloading the real-time one with indices (and therefore improving the write performance on that side).

Comment: What exactly is your analytics use-case and why do you think you need a NoSQL as the storage layer for Spark?
Will Spark perform any writes to this storage?
Do you need *search* capabilities on the data (Lucene)? or just processing
In short please provide some more information...

Comment: Spark might do some writes but this is not in the most common use case. I do not need "search" capabilities but rather `where` predicates capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with Lucene integration

Since **Cassandra 3.4**, we have a new secondary index called SASI that offers full text search and is quite performant.

Read this: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/doc/SASI.md

Comment: This indeed looks like the perfect solution. Is there a comparison Lucene v. Sasi somewhere?

Comment: No comparison yet, but SASI is much more performant for the local read path because the index structure provide the offset to read data directly from SSTable so there is no need to go through the normal Cassandra read path to fetch the source data

Comment: What about the case where you want sort capabilities on queries that only include the secondary indexes. I think this cannot be achieved using SASI